# Unable to pass image between view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, image, imageview, viewcontroller

As asked on the question. On my first VC, I have set up a function that passes an image to another VC as follows.

```
 @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer1: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let passimage = tapGestureRecognizer1.view as! UIImageView
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "...", message: "...", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "...", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Shop", sender: self)
            print("image tapped")
            
            let sb = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shopVC") as! shopVC
            sb.loadimage = passimage.image
            self.present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        alertController.addAction(ok)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "取消（留在此版面）", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

whilst on the other VC, I've set up an Image View which would read the image as shown here.

```
class shopVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var clothimage: UIImageView!
 var loadimage: UIImage?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        clothimage.image = loadimage
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
```

I know the "passimage.image" is what I want as it shows up in the debugging window - I can't seem to place it in the second VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for change ViewController you use two Option same Time, When used individually, each:

```
// optionOne
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Shop", sender: self)
                print("image tapped")

// optionTwo                
                let sb = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shopVC") as! shopVC
                sb.loadimage = passimage.image
                self.present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if use Option One, you must override below function from firstVC and set image directly:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? shopVC {
            vc.image = yourImage
        }
    }
```

and if you use present for show ShopVC nothing change code just comment performSegue function.
That means only the following code:

```
let sb = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shopVC") as! shopVC
                    sb.loadimage = passimage.image
                    self.present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hmmm... commented option one away, so left with ``` let sb = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shopVC") as! shopVC
                    sb.loadimage = passimage.image
                    self.present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil) ``` - Doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: This and Sergei's option of moving super.viewDidLoad above together solved the problem. Thanks@

Answer (score 0):

Need to call super.viewDidLoad() first and then setting up clothimage

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean moving ' clothimage.image = loadimage ' to below super.viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: This and Hassam's comment together helped! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, super.viewDidLoad(); clothimage.image = loadimage;